# How to use AJAX request to filter WFS data?

Tags: leaflet, wfs, filter, ajax, mashup

I want to create a mash-up that shows sites in Italy on a basemap. With the AJAX call I want to include the number of earthquakes within a certain distance to each site. I want to use the AJAX call for receiving and filtering the data. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Reason why `$.ajax` call does not work is missing `&outputFormat=application/json` parameter in the WFS url, so returned result is not JSON and so `$.ajax` rejects it. Since you don't have `error` function defined for `$.ajax`, error is simply ignored.

So WFS url should be:

```
url: 'https://emidius.mi.ingv.it/services/italy/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=italy:CPTI15_v2&cql_filter=DWITHIN(geom,Point(' + lat + '%20' + lon + '),50,kilometers)&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326'
```